# How to trigger debugger on dispatching a specific event while unsure of location of listener

Tags: javascript, debugging, extjs, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging JavaScript code in Chrome, is there a way to trigger the debugger on clicking an element - while not knowing the location of its listener? So, without a breakpoint in the source code.

I would set a breakpoint to step through what happens when an element is clicked, but sometimes I can't find the function. If there is an easier way than sifting through several files to find it, that would be most helpful.

When I try to find the location of the listener, I sometimes get a link to the library file, which I don't think is the listener itself.

[image: Observed under "Event Listeners"]

Comment: Set an event listener breakpoint in the Sources panel, https://puu.sh/FDGcK/06964cdcb1.png.